# Stop Notices From Displaying In PHP

Tags: php

I want my notices to stop displaying in PHP. Theres no errors in the code, it just says things like undefined index. Which nothing can be done about.

So how do I stop it from displaying?

```
Notice: Undefined variable: username in C:\wamp\www\watchedit\includes\config.php on line 37

Notice: Undefined variable: key in C:\wamp\www\watchedit\includes\config.php on line 42
```

Comment: Or just initialize your variables?

Comment: Closing the eyes to errors will not make them disappear.

Comment: I implore you to please write proper PHP code. Don't hide the notices, FIX WHAT IS CAUSING THEM.

Comment: These are not errors. Stop telling people to "avoid errors" like this and "write proper code". Notices are not errors, they are guesses of a proofreading parser, they're saying "hey, this might be a misunderstanding, just check on it to make sure it's what you wanted". But most of the time it is. So please don't litter your code with isset-like name duplications; if you can, use the double question mark operator, but otherwise just get rid of notices. They almost never help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This will turn off notices for the environment programmatically-- from PHP.net.

```
// Report all errors except E_NOTICE   
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

In some places, you can prefix the statement with "@" and it will silence just that location if it causes a notice.

Comment: to not display any errors, warning or notices use: error_reporting(0);

Comment: Great option if you absolutely need nothing to appear on a user's screen if something goes wrong. Those tend to cause weird support calls.

Comment: I assume that one then implements their own error handling methods which show more user friendly error messages than ones about undefined variables..

Comment: Notices are not problems with the code though, just suggestions. I don't ignore errors.

Answer (score 8):

You should check with [`isset`](http://docs.php.net/isset) if the variable exists before trying to read its value.

Answer (score 4):

> Which nothing can be done about.

This is not true in most cases. Undefined variables can be declared, undefined indices can be tested for using [isset(mixed...)](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

Also, you should configure your environment as suggested above using error_reporting(...). In production environments it is also recommended to disable [display_errors](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)

Comment: totally... This question, and some of these answers, are why php has such a bad reputation for code quality...

Comment: Here is a fixed url: [display_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)

Answer (score 2):

- Change `error_reporting` in php.ini
- Use `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE | ...)`
- ...or just fix what causes the notices to appear.

Answer (score 1):

Because i have no php.ini so i just put this tag right after

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Striving to generate no notices is a healthy goal, since they will then begin to flag up potential errors or problems. You can write your own error handler to log these, since they should (hopefully) be few and far between.